# Add id attribute to a link in draftjs

Tags: draftjs

I need to add 'id' attribute to an anchor created using draft-js `createEntity`.

This is what I tried:

```
const contentState = editorState
      .getCurrentContent()
      .createEntity('LINK', 'MUTABLE', { url, id: 123 });
```

The link is created but it doesn't get the id.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to get it done?

Comment: In our case, the id was being removed by some part of the code, we believe it was statetohtml as you can see here https://github.com/sstur/draft-js-utils/blob/fe6eb9853679e2040ca3ac7bf270156079ab35db/packages/draft-js-export-html/src/stateToHTML.js#L71, it supports only some attributes for link. So we started storing the id in `rel` tag and assigning it as id to link at the time of render, as a workaround.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks